# XStream and parse xml attributes

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have some xml that looks like:

```
<document>
    <item name="id">some value</item>
    <item name="first-name">some value</item>
    <item name="last-name">some value</item>
    <item name="address">some value</item>
    <item name="zip">some value</item>
</document>
```

POJO:

```
@XStreamAlias("document")
public class Doc{
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String zip;
}
```

EDIT:

The issue I am facing is that there are duplicate `<item>` tags causing xstream to throw an exception.  I am looking for a way to pull out the `id`,`first-name`,`last-name`, etc attributes from the `item` element

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the structure of your classes based on the XML provided:

Document:

```
@XStreamAlias("document")
public class Document {
    @XStreamConverter(value = ItemsConverter.class)
    private Items items;
}
```

Items:

```
public class Items {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String zip;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Provide a custom converter(ItemsConverter) which converts all the `<item>` tags to fields in Items object.

Custom converter:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

public class ItemsConverter implements Converter {


    @Override
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter hierarchicalStreamWriter, MarshallingContext marshallingContext) {
        // implement logic for marshalling to xml
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader hierarchicalStreamReader, UnmarshallingContext unmarshallingContext) {
        Items items = new Items();
        while (hierarchicalStreamReader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            hierarchicalStreamReader.moveDown();
            final String currentAttribute = hierarchicalStreamReader.getAttribute("name");
            if ("id".equals(currentAttribute)) {
                items.setId(hierarchicalStreamReader.getValue());
            } else if ("first-name".equals(currentAttribute)) {
                items.setFirstName(hierarchicalStreamReader.getValue());
            } else if ("last-name".equals(currentAttribute)) {
                items.setLastName(hierarchicalStreamReader.getValue());
            } else if ("address".equals(currentAttribute)) {
                items.setAddress(hierarchicalStreamReader.getValue());
            } else if ("zip".equals(currentAttribute)) {
                items.setZip(hierarchicalStreamReader.getValue());
            }
            hierarchicalStreamReader.moveUp();
        }
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class aClass) {
        return aClass == Items.class;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class XStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        XStream stream = new XStream();
        stream.processAnnotations(Document.class);
        Document document = (Document)stream.fromXML(new InputStreamReader(XStreamTest.class.getResourceAsStream(<your file name>)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've revised my question.  The issue is around pulling attributes from repeating element tags

Comment: What happens when I only want the `address` attribute?  Say for example I dont care about anything else about the person, except their address.  Would I have to iterate over all `item`s and apply conditional logic?

Comment: To get only the specific attribute without iterating all the items, you need to write a custom converter for the items field. look at the answer for custom converter

Comment: Thanks for a great example akki.  Just to be 100% clear, there is no other way to get the attributes without returning a `Map`?  I was hoping I could just populate the POJO with the xml attributes, but it doesn't look like that is possible with xstream.

Comment: there is one possibility but the converter will be very specific to your xml document structure. I added this in answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting a CannotResolveClassException: item when using your original suggestion of putting them into a `Map<String,String>`

Comment: This example does not work.  It ends up throwing an exception:

    Exception in thread "main"     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConvert    er$UnknownFieldException: No such field Document.item
    ---- Debugging information ----
    field               : item
    class               : Document
    required-type       : Document
    converter-type      :     com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
    path                : /document/item
    line number         : 2
    version             : 1.4.8
    -------------------------------