# Converting XML To Java Object With Common Node Name and Property in Attribute?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xstream

So I have a POJO that looks like this:

```
public class ShippingAddress
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    //All the getters and setters
}
```

The XML coming in, however, looks like this:

```
<ShippingAddress>
    <Data Name="Name">John Doe</Data>
    <Data Name="Address">123 Main Street</Data>
    <Data Name="City">Anytown</Data>
    <Data Name="State">AK</Data>
    <Data Name="Zip">98765</Data>
</ShippingAddress>
```

I typically use XStream for XML parsing, but I'm stumped on this one.  Would there be a solution using JAXB or some other XML parser?  Or it this probably going to just have an ugly solution creating an array of "Data" objects and then looping through them to create my useful POJO?

Thanks!

Comment: Shortly after I posted this, I found this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206426/xstream-and-parse-xml-attributes) which I think may provide the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess VTD-XML might help you. Below is the code, i haven't added null checks and stuff but it should be able to achieve what you are trying to get. Hope this helps!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;

public class ParseXML {

    private VTDGen vg;
    private VTDNav vn;
    private File f;
    private FileInputStream fis;

    public void parseFile(String inputfile){
        try {
            f = new File(inputfile);
            fis = new FileInputStream(inputfile);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        initialize();
        if(vg!=null)
            parse();
    }

    private void initialize(){
        try{
            byte[] ba = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            fis.read(ba);
            vg = new VTDGen();
            vg.setDoc(ba);
            vg.parse(false);
            vn = vg.getNav();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    private void parse(){
        vn.push();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.bind(vn);
        ap.resetXPath();
        try{
            ap.selectXPath("//ShippingAddress");
            while(ap.evalXPath()!=-1)
                loadData();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        vn.pop();
    }

    private void loadData(){
        vn.push();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.bind(vn);
        try{
            ShippingAddress sd = new ShippingAddress();
            ap.selectElement("*");
            while(ap.iterate()){
                //checking if current child element is Data
                if(vn.toRawString(vn.getCurrentIndex()).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Data")){
                    String attributeValue = "";
                    int i = vn.getAttrVal("Name");
                    if(i != -1)
                        attributeValue = vn.toString(i).trim();

                    String elementValue = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());

                    if(attributeValue.trim().equals("Name")){
                        sd.setName(elementValue);
                    }else if(attributeValue.trim().equals("Address")){
                        sd.setAddress(elementValue);
                    }else if(attributeValue.trim().equals("City")){
                        sd.setCity(elementValue);
                    }else if(attributeValue.trim().equals("State")){
                        sd.setState(elementValue);
                    }else if(attributeValue.trim().equals("Zip")){
                        sd.setZip(elementValue);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Add code/logic to save the newly created ShippingAddress sd object

        }catch(Exception e){}
        vn.pop();
    }
}
```